# Decryption method not working swift

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

I have encrypt and decrypt method , encrypt method working fine tested with c# encrypt and decrypt method, in android also working fine but **in swift decrypt method not working its show me null** i try many times  but not success , anyone help me regarding solve this problem highly appreciate because. i'm new in swift

PlainString = "5lg3yg7Q+Y8="

```
func tripleDesDecrypt(PlainString :String) -> String? {
       let md5Data = "FIFEDCBA98765432104AABFD"       
        if let keyData = md5Data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let data = PlainString.data(using: .utf8),
            let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(data.count) + kCCBlockSize3DES)  {
            let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)
            let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
            let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
            let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
            var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0
            let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                      algoritm,
                                      options,
                                      (keyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength,
                                      nil,
                                      data.bytes, data.count,
                                      cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted)
            if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
                cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
                let unencryptedMessage = String(data: cryptData as Data, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
                return unencryptedMessage
            }
            else {
                            return nil
            }
        }

        return nil
    }


func tripleDesEncrypt(PlainString: String) -> String{

   let md5Data = "FIFEDCBA98765432104AABFD"
 //   let md5Data = MD5(string:keyvalue)
    let PlainStringvar       = PlainString

    guard let data = PlainStringvar.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return ""
    }
    let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(data.count) + kCCBlockSize3DES)!

    let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)
    let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
    let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                              algoritm,
                              options,
                              md5Data.bytes, keyLength,
                              nil,
                              data.bytes, data.count,
                              cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                              &numBytesEncrypted)

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)

       var base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)


        return base64cryptString//// encodeString(str: base64cryptString)

    } else {
        print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the data and cryptData parameters the wrong way around in your decrypt function. The dataIn values ie crypted data are first and then the dataOut values follow ie decrypted data. It should be as follows

```
let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                          algoritm,
                          options,
                          (keyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength,
                          nil,
                          cryptData.bytes, cryptData.length,
                          data.mutableBytes, data.count,
                          &numBytesEncrypted)
```